# Multivariable Integral-Polar

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of the spherical wedge above $ z = r \cot \phi_o$ and below $z^2 + r^2 = \rho_0^2$, and on the sides by $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$.

I tried to set an iterated integral $$\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \int_{?}^{?} \int_{r \cot \phi_0}^{\sqrt{\rho_0^2-r^2}} r \, \, dz \, dr \, d\theta$$
However, I'm not sure how to find the limits for $r$.

The answer is given as $\frac{1}{3} p_0^3(1-\cos \phi_0)(\theta_2-\theta_1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the upper limit of $z$ should be $\sqrt{\rho_0^2-r^2}$ and then the limits of $r$ are $0$ and $(r \cot \phi_o)^2 + r^2 = \rho_0^2\implies r=\rho_0\sin \phi_0$